# How to determine the Shading Editor nodes that use a certain texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, linked-data

Is there a way to find the exact places (in the Shading Editor for example) where a certain texture is used? And is there in general a nice overview of all (external) assets in a `.blend`?

For reference, I use Poliigon's Material Converter add-on, which imports diffuse maps, AO maps, displacement maps, normal maps etc. and automatically creates a rather complicated node group with those, hence it is a little difficult to found textures. In order to keep the packed `.blend` small, I want to avoid packing textures which aren't actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a short overview

- List of all images is in *Outliner > Blender file > Images*
- List of unused images is in *Outliner > Orphan Data > Images*
- To delete selected items *Right Click > Delete*
- To remove all orphaned data at once (except those with Fake user) use the nice `Purge` button

(Blender also 'Purges' all unused and unprotected images when you close it.)

*There are three images in my file. Image 02 isn't used in any material so I can get rid of it.*

[image]